# Handlebars page re-rendering after a query doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, templates, nestjs, handlebars.js

I'm working on a handlebar's page that show some books. Books can be filtered by title or by author or by city/library.
The page is rendered well the first time, but if I use filters and recall the handler with new parameters, the query is executed well (I can see new books' list) but handlebar doesn't update the page with new data

here is a part of my code:

```
  @Get()
  @Render("ciclo/index")
  async getCicloBooks(
    @Query("ciclo") ciclo,
    @Query("codProv") codProvincia,
    @Query("comune") idComune,
    @Query("title") title,
    @Query("author") author
  ) {
    let books = undefined;
    let comuni = undefined;
    let librariesId = [];
    const libraries = [];
    let data = {};

    this.logger.debug("[getCicloBooks] ciclo: " + ciclo);

    const province = await this.cicloService.getProvince();

    // Titolo
    if (title != undefined) {
      this.logger.log(`[getCicloBooks] per ciclo: ${ciclo} e titolo ${title}`);

      const query = { ciclo: ciclo, title: title };
      books = await this.bookService.getBooksByAdvancedQuery(query);

      // TODO considerare che lo stesso libro può essere in più librerie
      data = {
        pageTitle: `Trovate n librerie che hanno in catalogo ${title}`,
        ciclo: `${ciclo}`,
        books: books,
        libraries: null,
        provincie: province,
        comuni: comuni,
        comune: null,
        author: `${author}`,
        title: `${title}`,
      };
    } // Autore
    else if (author != undefined) {
      this.logger.log(`[getCicloBooks] per ciclo: ${ciclo} e autore ${author}`);

      const query = { ciclo: ciclo, author: author };
      books = await this.bookService.getBooksByCicloAndAuthor(query);

      // TODO considerare che lo stesso libro può essere in più librerie
      data = {
        pageTitle: `Trovate n librerie con libri di ${author}`,
        ciclo: `${ciclo}`,
        books: books,
        libraries: null,
        provincie: province,
        comuni: comuni,
        comune: null,
        author: `${author}`,
        title: `${title}`,
      };
    } // Provincia e comune
    else if (idComune != undefined) {    
      this.logger.log(`[getCicloBooks] ciclo: ${ciclo} id comune ${idComune}`);
      const comune = await this.cicloService.getComune(idComune);
      const allLibraries = await this.cicloService.getAllLibrariesInCities();

      this.logger.log("[getCicloBooks] comune " + JSON.stringify(comune));

      librariesId = [];
      allLibraries.forEach((library) => {
        if (library.comune.id == idComune) {
          libraries.push(library);
          librariesId.push(library.id);
        }
      });
      this.logger.log("[getCicloBooks] ids " + JSON.stringify(librariesId));

      const query = { ciclo: ciclo, id: In(librariesId) };
      // join book e libreria oppure find in table book_library_libreria where libreriaID in [libreriaId])
      books = await this.bookService.getBooksByAdvancedQuery(query);
      // this.logger.log("[getCicloBooks] books " + JSON.stringify(books));

      books.forEach((book) => {
        const libs = [];
        book.library.forEach((l) => {
          librariesId.forEach((id) => {
            if (l.id == id) {
              libs.push(l);
            }
          });
        });

        book.library = libs;
      });

      // this.logger.log("[getCicloBooks] books " + JSON.stringify(books));

      data = {
        pageTitle: `Tutti i libri disponibili per il ciclo: ${ciclo}`,
        ciclo: `${ciclo}`,
        books: books,
        libraries: allLibraries,
        provincie: province,
        comuni: comuni,
        comune: comune,
        author: `${author}`,
        title: `${title}`,
      };
    } else {
      books = await this.bookService.getBooksByCiclo(ciclo);

      data = {
        pageTitle: `Tutti i libri disponibili per il ciclo: ${ciclo}`,
        ciclo: `${ciclo}`,
        books: books,
        libraries: null,
        provincie: province,
        comuni: comuni,
        comune: null,
        author: `${author}`,
        title: `${title}`,
      };
    }

    this.logger.debug("[getCicloBooks] books: " + JSON.stringify(books));

    if (books === undefined) {
      data = {
        title: "Book Store",
        subtitle: `Attualmente non abbiamo nessun libro in catalogo per il ciclo ${ciclo}`,
        books: null,
        province: province,
        comuni: comuni,
      };
    }
    // this.logger.log(books);

    return { viewData: data };
  }
```

while this is the template code that doesn't update when new data are given

```
{{#> app}}
{{#*inline "content"}}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div class="col">
      <input id="ciclo" name="ciclo" value="{{viewData.ciclo}}" type="hidden">
      <h3 class="fw-bold mt-5 text-center">{{ viewData.pageTitle }}</h3>
      <h4 class="fw-bold text-center">Raffina la tua ricerca:</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-auto">
    <!-- Navigatore delle Tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="ex1" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="tab1" href="#tabPlace" class="nav-link active" data-mdb-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tabPlace"
          aria-selected="true">Cerca per provincia e comune</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="tab2" href="#tabAuthor" class="nav-link" data-mdb-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tabAuthor"
          aria-selected="false">Cerca per autore</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="tab3" href="#tabTitle" class="nav-link" data-mdb-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tabTitle"
          aria-selected="false">Cerca per titolo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tabs navs -->
  </div>


  <!-- Tabs content -->
  <div id="search-content-tabs" class="tab-content">

    <!-- Cerca per comune -->
    <div id="tabPlace" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-2" style="border: 1px;">
          {{!-- blocco provincia --}}
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1" style="margin-top: 8px;"> Provincia:</div>
          {{#with viewData}}
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
            <select name="provincia" id="provinciaDropdown" class="form-select" aria-label="example">
              <option value="">Seleziona la Provincia</option>
              {{#each provincie}}
              <option value="{{codice}}">{{provincia}}</option>
              {{/each}}
            </select>
          </div>
          {{/with}}

          {{!-- blocco comune --}}
          <div class="col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 8px;"> Comune:</div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select id="comuneDropdown" name="comune" class="form-select" aria-label="example">
              <option value="">Seleziona il Comune</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- riga dei select provincia e comune -->

        <div class="row mt-4"> <!-- riga bottone cerca -->
          <div class="col-2">
            **<button id="cityBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onCityClicked(event)">Cerca</button>**
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Cerca per comune -->

    <!-- Cerca per autore -->
    <div id="tabAuthor" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-2" style="border: 1px;">

          {{!-- blocco autore --}}
          {{!-- <div class="col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 8px;"> Autore:</div> --}}
          <div class="col-lg-3 form-outline">
            <input id="formAuthor" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
            <label class="form-label" for="formAuthor">Cerca per autore del libro</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-4"> <!-- riga bottone cerca -->
          <div class="col-2">
            <button id="authorBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onAuthorClicked(event)">Cerca</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Cerca per autore -->

    <!-- Cerca per Titolo -->
    <div id="tabTitle" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-3">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-2" style="border: 1px;">

          <div class="col-lg-1 form-outline">
            <input id="formTitle" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
            <label class="form-label" for="formTitle">Cerca per titolo del libro</label>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row mt-4"> <!-- riga bottone cerca -->
          <div class="col-2">
            <button id="titleBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onTitleClicked(event)">Cerca</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Cerca per Titolo -->

  </div>
  <!-- Tabs content -->
</div>

<!-- Blocco Risultato ricerca -->
{{ log viewData}}
<ul id="booksPreview">
  {{#each viewData.books}}
  <li style="list-style-type: none">
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row bt-2" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 mb-2">
          <img src="/covers/{{getCoverImage}}" style="height: 320px; width: 230px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-lg-6 mb-2">
          <div class="text-md-start text-black text-capitalize fa-2x">{{title}}</div>
          <div class="text-md-start">Autore {{getAuthor}}</div>
          <div class="text-md-start">Prezzo {{getPrice}} €</div>
          <div class="text-md-start">Abstract {{getDescription}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 mb-2">
          <div class="bi-text-left ">
            <a href="/cart/{{id}}" class="btn bg-primary text-white align-bottom">Aggiungi al carrello</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>


<!-- Blocco Risultato ricerca -->

{{/inline}}
{{/app}}
```

And this is part of scripts's functions called on serch button click

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#provinciaDropdown").on("change", function () {
    console.log(`Selected provincia: ${this.value}`);

    var country_id = this.value;
    $("#comuneDropdown").html("");

    uri = `http://${host}:${port}/admin/getComuni?prov=${country_id}`;
    $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      type: "GET",
      success: function (result) {
        /* console.log(' Result listaComuni ' + result.viewData.comuni); */

        if ($.isArray(result.viewData.comuni)) {
          $("#comuneDropdown").html(
            '<option value="">Seleziona il Comune</option>'
          );
          comuni = result.viewData.comuni;
          for (i = 0; i < comuni.length; i++) {
            str = `<option value="${comuni[i].id}"> ${comuni[i].comune} </option>`;
            // console.log(str);

            $("#comuneDropdown").append(str);
          }
        } // isArray
      }, // success
    });
  }); // onChange

  $("#comuneDropdown").on("change", function () {
    var idComune = this.value;
    console.log(`Selected comune with id ${this.value}`);
  }); // onChange comuneDropdown

});

function onCityClicked(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var city = document.getElementById("comuneDropdown").value;
  var ciclo = document.getElementById("ciclo").value;
  console.log(`[onCityClicked] ciclo: ${ciclo} city: ${city} `);

  var uri = `http://${host}:${port}/ciclo?ciclo=${ciclo}&comune=${city}`;
  console.log(`[onCityClicked] uri: ${uri} `);
  $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
      data = result.viewData;

      console.log("----- SUCCESS -----");
    }, // success
  }); // ajax
}
```

So, from main page I show the book's page (default query is executed and template page is rendered successfully), then when I try to change filters, the book's page is called with choosen filters, the query is excuted well (I check logs) but the template doesn't update. I got the previous page

I added to original code the `<ul id=".."> <li></li> </ul>` tags, trying to intercept at runtime some action on id and clean the book's list before the new render, but I wasn't able to do

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code of the form and the inputs.

Comment: I have updated the code with your requests.

Comment: My understanding is that the initial page load renders the template on the server. You have an event listener on the front-end (FE) that makes an async (`$.ajax`) call to the server for some data. The fetched data is used to update a `<select>` menu. I think your expectation is that the template would somehow be re-rendered, but if you are rendering it server-side it won't re-render when the async call is made. You would need to have this template available and compiled on the FE so that your FE code can invoke it (presumably with the fetched data) and then replace the current HTML.